# getting text into contentpage from textbox which is in masterpage in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have one master page and one content page.
In my master page i have one textbox,one button and one content placeholder.
the aim is to change the text(not assigning into any fields just text/content of content page) in the content page with the text entered by the user in the textbox which is in the master page.
here is the problem

even though i changed the text in the textbox and button clicked the previous text is updated and no change in the content page...
 here is my code in master page

```
public partial class example : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    FileInfo fil = new FileInfo("c:/documents and settings/administrator/my documents/visual studio 2010/Projects/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/contentpage.aspx");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        contenttext.Text = File.ReadAllText(fil.ToString());
    }

    protected void clicked_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(fil.ToString(),this.contenttext.Text);
        Response.Redirect("contentpage.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: ...and in content page... it is empty? Please add missing code!

Comment: Please do more clear your query

Answer (score 1):

```
// Gets a reference to a TextBox control that not in 
// a ContentPlaceHolder
Textbox txt = (Textbox) Master.FindControl("masterPageLabel");
if(txt != null)
{
    Textbox1.Text = Textbox2.Text;
}
```

try this and put it on click of button in code behinde

Comment: thnx... and one more doubt dean....
in the button click event method i want to fetch the text in the textbox.
both the button and textbox are in master page.
the button click method is in its .cs file...
thnx dean in advance

Answer (score 0):

**//.aspx page**

and this is .cs page
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                    tb.ID = "textbox" + i.ToString();
                    tb.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                    MyPanel.Controls.Add(tb);
                }
        }

```
    protected void btnReadTextBoxValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <=5; i++)
        {
//Append the master page content place holder id with textbox then it find value and      work
            string str ="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$"+"textbox" + i.ToString();
            TextBox retrievedTextBox = FindControl(str) as TextBox;
        if (retrievedTextBox != null)
        {
            lblResult.Text = ((TextBox)retrievedTextBox).Text;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            lblResult.Text = "No text box has been created!";
        }

        }
```